# Python: List XML Files in Directory by Creation Date or number in file name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python (3.7) script that grabs a list of all files in a directory and goes through them in a for loop.

What I want to do is make sure only XML files are listed and the list of files is ordered either by creation date/time or by the number in a file name.

Currently using:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(self.config['report_directory']) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.config['report_directory'], f))]
```

The above works fine for getting a list of files in a directory but I haven't been able to get it to list by file creation date or by the number in a file name.

Filenames example:

```
log_2983_report.xml
log_3948_report.xml
log_2198_report.xml
```

Any suggestions/help appreciated.

Comment: You want to achieve it only using one line?

Comment: @ranifisch, nope, whatever number of lines I need to do to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced your `self.config(...)` with `dir`, so I can check it in my environment.

for sorting according to the number in the XML file name, you can sort using the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) method with optional [`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) parameter to sort according to the number in the file name/create/modification time.

```
import os

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, f)) and f.endswith('.xml')],
               key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1]))

print(files)
```

similarly, you can sort with the key to be the modification/creation time of the file, [`os.path.getmtime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) or [`os.path.getctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime). for full explanation of how you can extract these details in the correct way for your OS, see:

[How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)